# using Xcode as an IDE for c++ codes

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import existing c++ project into Xcode IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034286/import-existing-c-project-into-xcode-ide)

I have a bunch of c++ code that I would like to import in Xcode 4.2 and use its IDE features. My code is in two directory, include and src. I just want to import them to a project so that I can see list of my classes, their functions and create new ones. Also, I don't need to create makefile since I already have one. The main reason I want this is to use Xcode's suggestion features while writing my code.

My question is, which project should I select and how should I proceed?

Thanks a lot in advance
Cheers 
Eda

Comment: Here, use the top answer on this one :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034286/import-existing-c-project-into-xcode-ide

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034286/import-existing-c-project-into-xcode-ide // I've been too slow :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a project of type "External Build System", from the "Mac->Other" group. The template assistant asks you what build tool to use - it defaults to /usr/bin/make which is probably what you need.

Comment: Thanks Graham, I now created the project and added my files using Add Files to project but still I cannot see my classes, and I cannot see function suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

for make, open the New Project wizard, then Choose `OS X > Other > External Build System`

you then add sources to your project, and then you may need to specify some discovery paths in order for indexing and code completion to function properly.

Comment: Thanks Justin, What are discovery paths for? and how can I specify them?

Comment: Xc4's indexer is a proper compiler component. just like you would for a compiler, you may need to specify directories for the compiler to locate your source files (`-I`). that, or configure a target (redundant). set the build setting at the project level `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`. description:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428216/adding-system-header-search-path-to-xcode